# Do pure "machine learning" questions belong to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been bumping into many questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705463/how-do-i-improve-my-neural-network-output) lately, and I'm surprised most of them doesn't have any *"this question belongs to stats.stackexchange"*-like comments. When I find a question regarding, for instance, neural networks that doesn't have anything to do with a concrete implementation (aside from the `matlab` tag), my first thought is to flag it as `off-topic > belongs to Stats` and add a comment.

**(a) Am I doing the right thing here? (b) Then why is it so uncommon?**

EDIT:

After some comments and discussion, my understanding is that the answer to **(a)** is **yes**, and then **pure machine-learning questions do not belong to SO**. There is (I think) an open issue on *where* to put this OT stuff (my opinion: CrossValidated), but [I'll continue this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stackexchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms/254090#254090) in the thread pointed out in the comments). 
As for the answer to **(b)**, well... it was more a rhetorical question, but I'll commit myself to the glorious quest of hunting down all machine learning-related OT questions out there.

Comment: Maybe Comp Sci, maybe stats, but unless there's some code, it seems OT here

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stackexchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Comment: As long as it has to do with programming?

Comment: @MathiasMüller thanks, since SO isn't mentioned in that question I understand it is **not** the place for pure machine learning, as I thought

Comment: How would I program a machine learning algorith that determines for every machine learning related question whether it belongs to Stack Overflow or not?

Comment: we are already doing that with a "human-based" machine-learning  algorithm, where we train the "community" to classify questions as on- or off-topic :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I read OT as "On Topic" and was confused for a moment.

Comment: I mostly not voting against such question, because I am not sure if its fit or not. So not taking risk of flaging. May be same scenario with other people.

Comment: I'm not a fan of closing such questions. The help center says that if your question covers a software algorithm then it should be considered on topic, and ML is arguably just a class of software algorithms.

Answer (score 28):

I think the [linked question from Mathias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stackexchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) covers this well.

Also consider:

- If it is a question about **implementation details**, then it probably fits StackOverflow.  It *might* be too broad if it's not well focused.  We don't write entire implementations for some algorithm by request, but if they are focused on a certain detail of the implementation it is probably focused narrowly enough to be acceptable. (I know you mentioned in question text, but just to be explicit for people who don't read carefully)
- Not all machine learning techniques have a statistical basis, and thus [stats.stackexchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com) should not be a catch all for it. There are other non-statistical approaches to machine learning.  stats.stackexchange seems to be welcoming to all of them, but the non-statistical approaches may find a better audience on CS.
- There is rarely a broadly applicable rule of thumb for these types of things. We'll only end up writing some rule that gets religiously misinterpreted and innocent by-stander questions get hurt.
- Evaluate each question based on the criteria of the site within which it was asked.  **If it meets the criteria, you are done, do nothing else.**  Only if it does not meet that criteria do you then either:

  - Vote to close ***or***
  - Migrate to a site where the question meets that site's criteria

Comment: From stats (aka CrossValidated) page: "Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, **machine learning**, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization." As I understand, the site is for both statistics and machine learning (cmon, it is called CrossValidated, you can't be more machine learning than that! :D)

Comment: @KeillЯandor In my opinion, machine learning is about _prediction_ based on statistics. It's not difficult to imagine machine learning questions that are not about the statistics it relies on. But in general, CrossValidated seems a good fit for ML questions.

Comment: @KeillЯandor You are right. From the description of the machine-learning tag on stats, it seems they are fairly welcoming to a very broad range of questions.  Looking through tags that are usually non-statistical approaches, the site doesn't consider them unwelcome, although there were a great deal with no answers at all, so maybe pandering to an audience that isn't as familiar with these approaches.  The "grey area" between CS and Stats on machine learning is something that is culturally well known. Some questions that aren't strictly statistical approaches might get better response on CS.

Comment: @AaronLS I've always thought machine learning was more within Computer Sciences applications of AI.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Certainly some are within the realm of CS.  However, many modern applications employ a statistical approach. For example, Bayesian networks are well within the realm of statistical models, and are great at learning how to do things such as filter spam.

Comment: You can try to "follow" all the rules. You can enforce them for the sake of site-code and conduct. You can taunt "these" people asking the questions for it. That is not the thing at all. The reason they ask it here is, "Maybe now I have a chance to get an answer." SO favors the odds of that question being read more. You wanna be ethical about this, I am not stopping you but asking them isn't "totally" out of bounds of SO's tolerance limit either! I have been there.

Comment: @pulp_fiction you are wrong. First of all, nobody wants to *taunt* anyone. Second, using your argument ("SO favors the odds of that question being read more"), then I would ask a question about making chicken salad in SO (e.g. instead of doing it in SeasonedAdvice) because more people would read it in StackOverflow! Of course not all machine-learning questions are off-topic in SO, but those we are talking about definitely are.

Comment: @pulp_fiction I can understand what you are getting at.  Note that we favor NOT moving the question.  Sometimes questions may fit *better* on another site, but there is grey area, and as long as it meets the criteria of the site it was asked on, it should be left there.  So we do try to avoid unnecessarily frustrating users if moving isn't needed. If it doesn't meet the criteria though, **it would otherwise be closed as off topic**, so **we try to help users** out by moving the question to a more appropriate site.  This is why I bolded "If it meets the criteria, you are done, do nothing else."

Comment: @KeillЯandor : You wronged me at "taunt" -okay maybe I may have been but what you said, "then I would ask a question about making chicken salad in SO (e.g. instead of doing it in SeasonedAdvice)" stands for your argument's sake as a reply to me. It doesn't make any sense mixing opposite worlds because ML and SO both deal with Q&A of Computer Science though they intersect at a generic level.

Comment: @KeillЯandor :  About more views- Stackoverflow is a separate site www.stackoverflow.com  rather than <something>.stackexchange.com. SO is most popular then the rest, when you google the topic/question chances are if it is on SO, you get it as top results which means more accessibility.

Comment: I agree with above answer. No reason to install the Spanish Inquisition on Stack overflow. On the contrary, I would ease up. I do agree about training strategy questions, these are statistics.. but everyday practical NN will require programmers and it will require coding. Most NN topics you see now are pupils from school, asking about little XOR-net convergence and NN-basics like startup weight values and weights count. They still *code* that, to get the feel of what NN is. I would really advise SO not to leave so many future members in the dark, just because NN is not a 100% coding activity.