# Missing tags for probabilistic programming

Tags: support

May I ask the community to create some tags for me? Great! This would be:

- approximate-bayesian-computation
- anglican
- pyabc
- abcpy

**Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)** is a [bayesian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bayesian) based approach to [approximate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approximate) solutions for models based on statistical inference. ABC-methods generate samples from a distribution which is not the true posterior distribution of interest, but a distribution which is hoped to be close to the real posterior distribution of interest.

**[Anglican](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~fwood/anglican/index.html)** is a [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) based programming language for probabilistic programming.

**[pyABC](http://pyabc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** is a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) framework for [approximate-bayesian-computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approximate-bayesian-computation), especially for distributed, likelihood-free inference.

**[ABCpy](http://abcpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)** is a highly modular, scientific library for [approximate-bayesian-computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/approximate-bayesian-computation) written in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). It is designed to run algorithms by [parallel-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parallel-processing) using the [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) or [mpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpi) framework.

Comment: Couldn't find any posts referring to either pyABC or ABCpy...

Comment: Tags can only be created when asking questions, editing questions, or by moderators. Please provide existing questions per tag that should be created. If there are none, the tag should be created when someone actually has a question about one of these things.

Comment: I think you shouldnt create topics with that much specific tags. You can use clojure, python etc. as tags and mention ABCpy in a topic name...

Comment: [approximate-bayesian-computation] sounds like yet another tag that could mistakenly hint some people that technology-agnostic questions about statistical inference (including machine learning) are on-topic here. I say we keep it away unless we _do_ find out that enough people are asking good questions about related implementation details.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen it, but Cross Validated has the [abc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abc) tag.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your support. 
@yivi: I agree there isn't a post neither on pyABC nore on ABCpy - therefore no need  for this tags so far.

Comment: @libik: Ok, let's use clojure and python instead.

Comment: And thanks to @BilltheLizard for his hint on Cross Validated.

Comment: Are these related to programming?  As in, would a software developer be using this, or is this more for statisticians?

Comment: @Makoto Doesn't that depend on what you call a software developer? Even data scientists do some programming to design and produce their models and data pipelines.

Comment: @E_net4:  No, there is an *acute* difference between a data scientist and a programmer.

Comment: @Makoto Is your stance that we should never include these tags, then? And that tags such as [tag:scikit-sklearn] or [tag:caffe] do not belong here? I do stand against a majority of machine learning questions in SO, but I would like to understand where you would draw the line.

Comment: @E_net4:  For the most part I'm following [the on-topic guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  If it's the case that questions tagged as above represent unique problems related to software development, then I don't have an issue with this.  The questions with the above tags mentioned likely pertain to their usage of those libraries in a specific programming capacity.  Anything that describes these concepts or languages in any other fashion would be less than ideal to have around.

Answer (score 2):

No. Tags are created for questions and not because someone just like some tags.

If you want any particular tags to be created one possible route is to ask enough (I'd say 100 would be good start) on-topic, practical and non-duplicate, well received questions about given library/topic or just find such existing questions. Than ask to create tags with search queries showing off these questions.

**On the particular tags**:

There is very good chance that none of suggested topics would ever get enough questions to deserve own tags. Most likely SO part of using those libraries simply fits into basic language tag (Python or Closure correspondingly) and pure ABC questions would simply be off-topic (see similar discussions on Machine learning -  [Do pure "machine learning" questions belong to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/do-pure-machine-learning-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow) and [Which Stack Exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms)).

Other sites on SE network would be a better fit for non-coding part of such questions. In particular as [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) suggested Cross Validated has the [abc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abc) tag<sup>*</sup> that seem to have reasonably well received questions.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>don't use "[stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com) has just 30 questions and created the tag" as excuse to create on one SO - there are 100x more questions on SO than on Stats and thresholds for everything are generally higher on SO.</sub>