# Stack Exchange on Data Science and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I wanted to know if there is a known borderline separating questions on Stack Overflow from data science, as I encounter many questions on Stack Overflow about stuff like neural network, machine learning, optimization, etc. that though covering a coding objective, they also need vast information in the specific data science topic.

Comment: We have a whole site for the non-coding/science part: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Many of the questions that you have seen here might be off-topic for Stack Overflow, unfortunately. Related meta questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352404/1233251

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no hard borderline between Stack Exchange sites.  Generally sites can overlap, and it is best to check the [/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site to see what is appropriate for that site.

SO question should be:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

[Data Science questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) can be programming related but they must be specific to a Data Science Problem.