# Are questions about visualizations of neural networks on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Neural networks are pretty complex things and definitely programming-related. However, I've come across a question where neither I nor a few of my peers in chat can tell whether it's on-topic or not.

The question is [Convolutional Neural Network visualization - weights or activations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616888/convolutional-neural-network-visualization-weights-or-activations)

And it is asking to identify a highlighted section of an *illustration* of a conv neural network. So there is no code involved, but you can technically suss out some "logic" based on looking at the pictures.

Is this question (and questions like it) within the scope of Stack Overflow?

Comment: _"neural networks are pretty complex things and definitely programming-related"_ Whether deep learning is programming-related is actually subjective. You may find additional points of view in [this cross-meta question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4510/67965) and [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352404/1233251). It's a form of machine learning which can be scrutinized in a technology-agnostic fashion. The linked question in particular is answerable, but I'd argue that it fits in a community of data scientists more than in a community of programming enthusiasts.

Comment: Related also: [Do pure machine learning questions belong on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). Whether this question is _pure machine learning_ might just be the root of this confusion.

Comment: I'm not pretending to know the first thing about convolutional neural networks so I won't make a judgement call as to the on-topic-ness of the question, but assuming that the question does end up being on topic, it would be a lot more useful for future users if the question was about how to tell the difference between weights or activation, not just a question to identify one such weight or activation. "How to tell if a convolutional neural network visualization shows weights or activations" seems like it would still give the answer they need, and be easier to find by others too.

Comment: @DavyM The question also lacks context. Wherever the figure is from is likely to state that the visualization refers to the _weights_ and it's not something that would be mixed together with a graphical representation of its activations (unless they were made by a visualization tool with very bad UI).