# In 2018, why do high profile off-topic [machine-learning] questions remain open?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been visiting some highly voted [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) questions lately. A recurring motif I noticed is that most of them look borderline off-topic to me.

Let's recapitulate the tag excerpt for [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning)

> Implementation questions about machine learning algorithms. General
>   questions about machine learning should be posted to their specific
>   communities.

---

We had this similar question on meta some years ago: [Do pure "machine learning" questions belong to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/do-pure-machine-learning-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow). The landscape seems to have ameliorated regarding new questions, but I haven't seen much involvement regarding the older, high profile questions.

The consensus back in 2015 was:

> - If it is a question about implementation details, then it probably fits Stack Overflow. It might be too broad if it's not well focused.
> - We don't write entire implementations for some algorithm by request, but if they are focused on a certain detail of the
>     implementation it is probably focused narrowly enough to be
>     acceptable. (I know you mentioned in question text, but just to be
>     explicit for people who don't read carefully)
> - Not all machine learning techniques have a statistical basis, and thus stats.stackexchange should not be a catch all for it. There are
>     other non-statistical approaches to machine learning.
>     stats.stackexchange seems to be welcoming to all of them, but the
>     non-statistical approaches may find a better audience on CS.
> - There is rarely a broadly applicable rule of thumb for these types of things. We'll only end up writing some rule that gets religiously
>     misinterpreted and innocent by-stander questions get hurt.
> - Evaluate each question based on the criteria of the site within which it was asked. If it meets the criteria, you are done, do nothing
>     else. Only if it does not meet that criteria do you then either:
>
>   - Vote to close or
>   - Migrate to a site where the question meets that site's criteria

---

Now I'll list the five most voted questions in the [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag (all open):

1. [Role of Bias in Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks)
2. [What is the difference between a generative and a discriminative algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879432/what-is-the-difference-between-a-generative-and-discriminative-algorithm)
3. [A simple explanation of Naive Bayes Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059594/a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification)
4. [Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)
5. [Which machine learning classifier to choose, in general?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595176/which-machine-learning-classifier-to-choose-in-general)

In my opinion, only question 4 is on-topic. Yet they are all open. I understand they can't be moved, but they should be closed as off-topic, no?

---

### TL;DR:

Question is, then, could/should these high-profile, highly voted, off-topic machine learning questions be closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

It's *roughly* the same problem as old questions in general: they may pass through the curation radar undetected back when they were created, and so they continue to live now. Although you are free to flag them to be closed (with the most suitable reasons), we usually prefer to act when they attract recent actions, such as when a new answer is given to such a question. This in general allows those with closure votes to "invest" them on active content, where they are better applied.

Hence, we should instead worry about recently asked questions. There is still a low number of curators around tags related with machine learning, and some of those are even becoming increasingly popular (i.e. [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow)). This reverts to what was said back in  [Can we improve our stance on off-topic questions about deep learning?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352404/1233251) The curation process has improved since the call, but it also needs to keep up with the increase of questions in those tags.

One more important note, however: as you well mention, not all questions involving machine learning in some way are off-topic *per se*. #4 lacks research effort and could be closed as too broad (there are currently multiple ways of saving a model, and one might have to scroll through several answers to find what they are looking for), but it's still about using the TensorFlow API, which is on-topic.  Some level of discrimination is advised here, as there are also borderline questions in which there is no consensus on their on-topicness (see for example [Are questions about visualizations of neural networks on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371811/1233251) ).

With that said:

1. If you find a new or active question which you are *sure* that it's not about programming in any way, or has other issues which merit closure, please flag/vote to close it.
2. Voting to migrate to Cross Validated is only advised if the question itself is good enough for that site. The traditional "don't migrate crap" sentence applies here.
3. As old questions seem to have been considered useful nevertheless, I don't think they are in a position to be *deleted* from the site. The closure would hopefully serve as enough of a signpost to prevent users from asking the same sort of questions, while keeping the content available to everyone.

Comment: "This in general allows those with closure votes to "invest" them on active content, where they are better applied." That's where the problem is, and it's a technical one. New questions should be in a closed state by default, and if it gets blessed for opening, the score should be reset and comments up to that point removed. This is of course far too radical to propose in a new post, but it's the conclusion I've come to from years of thinking about the problem and also experiencing it live.