# Dealing with questions about improving the accuracy of neural networks

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

I've seen a lot of questions formed like this:

> #### My neural network is performing badly
>
> I have the following neural network, but it has a validation of only 0.6 and I need at least 0.9
>
> ```
> Some code for a neural network, with no obvious issues
> ```
>
> I trained in on [some publicly available dataset]. I've tried everything. Can someone help?

This technically has a reproducible example and a exact description of the actual and desired result. Yet the only way to "solve" it is just to somewhat randomly mess around with the hyperparameters till you get the desired result. Of course, an expert in the field would be able to better intuit what parameters to tweak and in which direction thus reach the desired result much faster than a beginner.

It doesn't seem like such questions would be helpful here since the only real possible answers are "did you try changing X?" or maybe a completely different model by someone who tried that dataset before.

If it should be closed, I don't know what it should be closed as. It's plenty detailed, has debugging details, is focused, is definitely about programing.

Recent example: [Problem with the neural network that recognizes images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863403/problem-with-the-neural-network-that-recognizes-images)

Comment: I have a feeling this is not necessarily about *programming* and thus off-topic, but I don't know if there are any SE sites that accept such questions. [ai.se]? [datascience.se]? [stats.se]?

Comment: And also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378431/guidance-for-asking-machine-learning-questions

Comment: You are right that questions such as the example given are hard to ever be useful here. The example is a blatant case of "do the research and experimentation for me until it reaches metric X".

Comment: I feel that most of these are fundamentally no different from asking "what hostname should I connect to?", "what password must I enter?", and similar things depending on the environment, not the program. Ultimately, these aren't programming issues.