# Are research questions on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423053/why-are-carboard-boxes-hard-to-detect) was asked twice in the Stack Exchange network because the OP didn't find good answers in the other network.

This looks like a research question to me and I immediately flagged it as opinion based (which I think is incorrect).

The question is not about code but it just mentions datasets and architectures. Is this question on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352404/can-we-improve-our-stance-on-off-topic-questions-about-deep-learning

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373969/in-2018-why-high-profile-off-topic-machine-learning-questions-remain-open