# Why am I getting downvotes on my detailed & relevant question?

Tags: support

I posted a question yesterday and I have 2 votes to close, 0 upvotes. Nobody has bothered to tell me what's wrong, and as always, I feel extremely frustrated trying to get help on this website. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong with this question?
[Classifier for time-series data with tensorflow.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335151/classifier-for-time-series-data-with-tensorflow-js/61353901#61353901)

This question is generally well-formed because:

1. It's detailed.
2. It's concise.
3. It's highly relevant: ML is a hot technical topic, and tensorflow is terse, and unintuitive to LOTS of developers
4. The documentation for the JS library of tensorflow is simply not as good as the python documentation, and it's not obvious how the python implementation maps the JS implementation.

Could the question be improved? Yes, almost certainly. I think that when I first wrote it, I didn't have enough information to ask the right question. That being said, I still don't know that I have enough info to form the right question. What would really help is for someone to answer the question to simply point me in the right direction. What doesn't help is people voting my question down and saying absolutely nothing.

Why is it so terrible to expect people to just answer the question? Developers exist at many different levels, and just because this question doesn't currently dig into the specifics of data annotation, doesn't mean it's won't be helpful to some people (probably people at the same level as me right now).

Comment: I don't know much about tensorflow, but if I'm reading your question correctly, you're basically asking for a tutorial, which isn't on-topic.

Comment: Even if I could agree with you, why can't SO simply require that reviewers say as much, and allow the asker to improve the question?

Comment: @rm.rf.etc [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/8967612) I don't necessarily agree with all the reasons but you may check it out anyway.

Comment: Ahmed, ya, thanks for the link. Had seen this before. I don't agree with it, and note that, the asker has more upvotes than the answerer has.

Robert Longson, I don't have a working python example, but then, is that a requirement? Seems like a lot to ask. My core skill is JS.

Comment: Part of the question is simply, "Should I use LSTM for this use case?". The next part is, "How do I annotate data of this type?". Yes, I can add some of my code, but it's basically copied from tutorials I've found. What's missing from these tutorials is what brings me to this website: How do I form annotated (labeled) data for tensorflow?

Comment: No, I never said I understand the python documentation. Don't put words in my mouth. Why are you making this so confrontational? What I said is "it's not obvious how the python implementation maps the JS implementation". What I'm saying is that I'm finding it difficult to find the answer I need, and while the python docs are better (I think the majority of TF users are on python), it's not helping.

Comment: @rm.rf.etc - “How do I form annotated (labeled) data for tensorflow?” - This might be your question but you didn’t actually ask it.  However, your question on how Python implementation maps the JS implementation would be out of scope for Stack Overflow.  As for feedback, the close reason, is your feedback.

Comment: I don't know about the tech there but the question seems very compressed and specific to me. Paired with the fact that there is no own effort visible, the question invites some people to downvote. (4 out of 60)

Comment: Downvotes can also be used to indicate the answer is wrong, often subtly or dangerously so.

Comment: Additional consideration: post tagged "javascript"+"node.js" to get probably 10% of SO users to look at it... Most of them would come to say "nothing in this question makes sense, not even related to JavaScript... and asks for opinions... looks like a strange and maybe bad question". I'm not sure if anything can be done about it but maybe you don't need to tag beyond "tensorflow"...

Comment: _"I don't agree with it, and note that, the asker has more upvotes than the answerer has."_ You misunderstood the context of this meta question. The asker and the answered are the _same users_, who aimed to create a canonical Q&A for this subject so frequently raised. The upvotes reflect the fact that the user base agrees that the question is useful, not that they wish for feedback alongside downvotes to become mandatory.

Answer (score 8):

This was a question I found by chance. I voted to close it because it suffers from the main key problems that most questions about machine learning have when they are posted here on Stack Overflow.

- The decision of whether to use an LSTM or not is more of a *research decision*, one that is technology agnostic and might not even make as much sense after a few years.
- That you are using Node.js instead of Python is not a relevant difference, once you start asking about which neural network architecture is "better" for the problem (for which we did not have a sufficiently complete example). Questions about API use should be very specific about what you wish to build.
- Even if you had some code to work as a baseline, the question of how to improve it would have been too open ended and is hard to manage properly in this context.
- It did not help either that the answer within contained a complaint about downvotes. Please refrain from putting meta-commentary on your posts.

See also:

- [Standard for machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380942/standard-for-machine-learning-questions)
- [Guidance for asking machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378431/guidance-for-asking-machine-learning-questions)