# How can I ask a good question on machine learning (ML)?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am about to ask one of the first questions involving [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow). I am trying to follow this guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

The questions I have seen previously on [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) topics had very long code part and did not summarize the problem succinctly. However, I find it hard to present questions about a later stage of a process (i.e., how to improve the model) without having to engage in lengthy discussion of how I prepared my data and what exactly I am feeding to my ML model. This is however, seems necessary to fulfill the **Introduce the problem before you post any code** & **Help others reproduce the problem** requirement of the mentioned guide.

This way, the question becomes excessively long.

I have seen quite a lot of questions seemingly having the same problem is mine, so while these questions might be suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I believe (or hope) that there is a way to ask them on Stack Overflow as well.

What are the good practices for asking such questions?

---

My question ended up being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943622/how-to-improve-accuracy-of-model-for-categorical-non-binary-foreign-language-s).

Comment: Isn't there also a [ML-specific Stack Exchange site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)? Not suggesting this *isn't* a good fit for SO, but if you know a site that it's a good fit for (Code Review), why try to force it into a different site (SO)?

Comment: The same way you ask a good question about any other topic.  Machine Learning is not special in this regard.

Comment: @TylerH, thanks, that's good idea! Will check it out. (In my experience, when I have a question which would fit well to multiple sites, SO is the one where my question gets bigger exposure - that's why I'm trying to put it there.)

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380942

Comment: @TylerH, Looked into https://stats.stackexchange.com, they don't deal with implementation questions, but https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ seem to, so if my edit for reopening doesn't succeed I can try there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing I notice is that your question actually contains a whole *list* of questions at the end. Stack Overflow is ideally the place to ask *one question at a time*. The more questions you ask in a single question, the more likely you are to get partial/fragmented answers that may answer different parts of your question. Which one do you accept then? Additionally, it's possible people won't be able to provide succinct answers and end up writing whole blog posts for answers, which is something SO wants to avoid.

Specific thoughts on your questions list:

> Is there room for improvement in data preparation?

This question seems too broad/open-ended for me. More appropriate for Code Review. There's almost always room for improvement in a *process* someone shares.

> adding additional Convolutional / LSTM / GRU layers (what combination, number of them)?

What are your criteria for the ideal response here?

> How to decide if a layer should have more / less neurons?

Probably OK, may be too broad

> Can I expect significantly higher accuracy from significantly more training data?

Seems OK to me (also seems like an obvious "yes" but I'm not in the ML field).

> Given that it will be used in a real world environment, encoder was built using the most common words in the language, not the words of the training data. Is this good practice?

Best practices are off-topic on Stack Overflow as they are primarily opinion-based things.

A second thing I notice is that you follow up your question list with a request/encouragement for resource recommendations:

> Comments & recommendation of resources are also welcome.

I would *recommend* you remove that, as resource recommendation requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Everyone should ideally just be *recommending* **the solution** to a given problem or question via the answer function.

Comment: (Updated the post since this answer was written, old post can be found in edit history.)

Answer (score 5):

Picture yourself trying to answer the question. If as the answerer, there is sufficient data to answer and be certain the answer is correct, then you should be feel comfortable posting.

As for how to best determine what sufficient data means, I would highly suggest taking some tips from Jon Skeet's [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).