# Deep learning questions almost never have minimal reproducible examples

Tags: discussion, questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I've noticed a recurring issue that I believe we can improve upon. Admittedly, I'm not entirely sure what the solutions should be, but I think that these problems should be outlined. Within SO's ML communities, particularly in tags like [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch), [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) and [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), there seems to be a huge lack of [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) accompanying questions. ML problems often have a certain level of complexity that make them difficult to reproduce (let alone *minimize*), but we should strive for clarity to foster effective problem-solving.

I believe that most of the machine learning questions on SO are impossible to answer based on the information given, many of the *"answers"* in the ML community come under the *advice* column. The problem is especially rampant in the ML communities due to the nature of the underlying tech. I think that most of the questions in the ML community would be closed if everyone followed the SO policies to a tee, almost nobody would receive help, as opposed to say, questions under the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, which are often much more reproducible.
Many questions we encounter are along the lines of "Why doesn't my model improve?" or "Why did I get this error?" These are valid questions that often require detailed responses, but without an accompanying minimal reproducible example, it becomes significantly more challenging to provide concrete, useful answers.

Let's take a look at some of the common issues that can arise when posing ML questions on SO:

- **Dataset is too large**: When dealing with big data, it can be challenging to present a simplified version of the problem. In many scenarios, issues can probably be reproduced with a subset of the data. We could encourage users to use a sample of their data that can still exhibit the problem when posing their question.
- **Long Training Time**: Machine learning models, particularly deep learning ones, can often take an untrivial amount of time to train. This makes the process of testing different things to see if they work much longer.
- **Extensive Source Code**: In some cases, the problem might be embedded in a large codebase, which isn't practical to share in a Stack Overflow question.
- **Data is private**: When answerers do not have access to the data involved, it often makes it difficult to find solutions.
- **Enormous GPUs**: Not everyone has access to high-end computational resources. When a problem is specific to such environments, we could encourage the use of code that can reproduce the behavior with smaller, more manageable computations. It's beneficial to isolate the problem from the size of computations wherever possible.
- **Different environments**: ML software packages and environments vary greatly and can contribute to unique issues.

The rapid development and widespread application of deep learning technologies calls for robust and efficient problem-solving platforms. Stack Overflow, with its vast community of experts and learners, is uniquely positioned to facilitate this process. I would love to hear different viewpoints about this dilemma.

Regarding comments along the lines of *"This isn't what Stack Overflow is for."* This prompts me to question, if not Stack Overflow, where should we as developers turn to? As an independent developer, my resources may not stretch to maintaining a dedicated support desk. Surely, fostering a spirit of collective problem-solving is part of the essence of such a community? This naturally leads to another concern: *Given that corporations are often behind many of the major advancements in AI, how might we bolster the contributions of independent developers?*

Comment: Humans are lazy & won't research their problem or site usage & don't know how to communicate or organize or isolate a problem with an artifact or their reasoning. It's the same problem as on every site. Vote to close.

Comment: @philipxy I almost read your comment as if you're suggesting to vote to close this Meta question, with the reasoning that it's pointless, because of what you wrote beforehand. So to be clear; vote to close the questions. If a question cannot be answered, close it. It's the only way that askers will learn to respect the rules of the site.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship My comment was a laconic answer. I guess you end up interpreting it that way & paraphrasing it.

Comment: I guess maybe this post is about getting good MREs for ML questions given that there are ML-specific difficulties constructing/giving MREs for ML questions. But your post doesn't make that clear. (It's buried in the bullets.)

Comment: It's an [old problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352404/can-we-improve-our-stance-on-off-topic-questions-about-deep-learning), and unsurprisingly getting ever more aggravated. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380942/standard-for-machine-learning-questions/380954#380954

Comment: Your edit didn't improve the problems mentioned in my comment about your goal being unclear. (You don't state your main goal & though you make a lot of statements/observations you don't clearly connect them to it.) (Also it's not clear what you are trying to express via "... , rather ...".) I suggest you read your post to see what it actually says.

Comment: @philipxy I made a few more edits, but I am having trouble figuring out what else I can say to clarify my post. The stated goal of the post is to gather opinions about the problems involved in reproducing/minimizing ML questions, I tried to make everything in the post related to that.

Comment: "I believe that most of the machine learning questions on SO are impossible to answer based on the information given..." That belief should be tested. Are most machine learning questions answered? The minimal reproducible example requirement is specifically for debugging questions. However, if the question is answerable also without than that's an exception. If not, just close these questions and be done with it. It's on the question asker to provide all information so that a question is answerable. Non-answerable questions simply get closed.

Comment: @Trilarion I would argue that most ML questions are debugging problems, (i.e.: why isn't it learning, why is it giving an error). The asker could potentially post, say, a github page with all the details in it. But it seems a little bit... silly, to have to share your entire project every time you want an answer. On top of it, it makes it so that the post eventually might not contain all of the relevant information, it becomes subject to change to do the link. Showing differences btwn a snapshot ("commit") of the repo when asking the question, and snapshot after it's answered might be useful.

Comment: @BrockBrown The minimal part means that one has to invest effort to make the project as small as possible before asking here. Often enough that already solves the problem by itself. If it doesn't answerers might still guess (correctly) the solution even without being able to reproduce the problem. To see how many of the ML questions are answerable, we need to inspect them and close all those that do not seem to have a working answer or do not contain enough information to be answerable. I just say we need to check more of these questions before concluding they aren't answerable.

Comment: It's all about answerability. On SO we want meaningful questions with meaningful answers. If we can answer ML questions without examples that's okay. If we can't we can think of how to best provide these examples (that's your question here if I understand correctly). And if that is not possible, we can only close these questions unfortunately. Because the goal is to create a collection of good questions with answers. But I don't know enough about these tags to say how far away they are currently from that.

Comment: Hear hear. Related to this, I've seen an epidemic of people who are expecting to be able to write programs that do complex ML tasks while demonstrably not understanding any kind of programming fundamentals.

Comment: Related: *[Guidance for asking machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378431/)*, *[Do pure "machine learning" questions belong to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/)*, and *[How can I ask a good question on machine learning (ML)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399477/)*.

Comment: *"Stack Overflow, with its vast community of experts and learners, is uniquely positioned to facilitate this process"* - no it isn't. Because this is not and never will be a support desk. It is a site where too many people try to misuse it as one. Perhaps a Stack Exchange site dedicated to deep learning might be the way to go, but trying to use Stack Overflow for what it absolutely isn't is only going to end in tears.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you want to discuss? We have other "sub-communities" with similar inherent problems, be it distributed, embedded, domain, or otherwise specialised computing, that would tick most if not all "issues that can arise" yet they manage to consciously boil down their problems just fine. Taken at face value, it seems the appropriate response is that *yes we should follow* the SO policies to a tee as for everything else, but some of the assertions ("foster effective problem-solving", "almost nobody would receive help", etc.) suggest you rather want an exception?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm looking to discuss other possible hurdles and solutions to those problems. Something like Colab for Stack Exchange would be a great start, but I don't think that it checks all the boxes. Also, Stack Exchange may not have the resources for such a thing, and so I would encourage a more lightweight solution if it's at all possible, which I really think it is. Maybe Microsoft or Google would be willing to sponsor the compute side? Microsoft bought Github not too long ago, they seem interested in that kind of data.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think "throw tons of resources payed for by someone else at the issue" is the solution. Rather, it is the problem – encouraging people not to care about being able to cut down their code and samples for examples and problem demonstrators.

Comment: They seem to be 1) homework tags and 2) have a *staggering* number of unanswered questions. 3) The rate of ***[posting text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*** is also very high. None of the three are necessarily correlated (for instance, 1) and 2) aren't in some of [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) [homework tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)).

Answer (score 6):

I think this is looking at things the wrong way around:
We do not require an MRE for debugging because questions without it are unanswerable. We do require an MRE because questions with it are *reusable*.
Similarly, "Why doesn't *my* model improve?" and "Why did *I* get this error?" usually are not valid questions that require detailed responses. A general "Why doesn't model X improve in situations like Y?" are the questions where effort to respond actually helps the most.
Y'know, building a library of useful knowledge and all that stuff...

Lack of MREs, or generality, or whatnot on these ML/AI questions is not the problem, it is a symptom. Namely a symptom of the underlying problem that such questions<sup>1</sup> are inherently not meant to benefit anyone else. As such, these questions are not fit for Stack Overflow.
That this is a challenge for people seeking help, or that we could encourage them to do things they demonstrably do not care about won't change that. Ultimately, trying to cram them into Stack Overflow when we can see that things do not fit is not going to be helpful in the long run.

What to do about that? Well, for a start: follow the SO policies to a tee.

---

<sup>1</sup>Really "such questions", not necessarily all ML/AI questions.

Comment: I've said this before in this post, but I feel like it's important to emphasize. We are beginning to see models with increasingly "general" capabilities, rather than "niche" capabilities. As these models emerge, when somebody solves someone's problem, you will see gains in the "general" domain, rather than just the "niche" domain. An example, "my generative model can't make hands", if you solve this then you might end up with overall more coherent details in the output. I think that this type of thing will fuel the motivation for a volunteer based ML Q&A platform.

Comment: @BrockBrown That's nice for a volunteer based ML Q&A platform. [SO] isn't one.

Comment: Would you agree that such a thing should exist somewhere? If not Stack, then who?

Comment: @BrockBrown If you ask me directly, then no, the questions under discussion here are a waste of human and other resources IMO. Yes, AI/ML can have a huge and beneficial impact; no, that doesn't generally apply to the run-of-the-mill questions we get here. A platform to waste even more resources and encourage even more careless behaviour isn't something I think should exist.

Comment: If I'm being completely honest with myself, I think that I agree that many, probably most, of the questions in ML tags are wasteful, and as it stands a solution to most of these problems would not benefit the community as a whole. Despite that, I think that we should prepare ourselves to be able to solve ML problems in a more focused, coordinated way in anticipation of the more general models. Also maybe the existence of such a platform would be the kick needed to incubate the ideas required to construct more general models.

Answer (score 4):

> The rapid development and widespread application of deep learning technologies calls for robust and efficient problem-solving platforms. Stack Overflow, with its vast community of experts and learners, is uniquely positioned to facilitate this process. I would love to hear different viewpoints about this dilemma.

These are some ***really*** lofty expectations of the community.

My Cliff Notes version of this answer is:  Stack Overflow is better suited for questions that others can *reasonably* answer.

What do I mean by this?  Basically, assuming one has all of these things:

- an IDE or text editor
- a moderately or reasonably powerful computer
- <s>expertise</s> a passing familiarity in the language or library
- the means to run the code locally

...one could attempt to answer just about every question here.

With deep learning, you're talking about very *specialized* hardware and equipment.  Not everyone's going to be walking around with a GPU capable of doing this, nor have the financial means to have access to one, let alone *use it for free* to answer *your™* question.  That's even before we start talking about the tens or hundreds of gigabytes worth of data someone's trying to feed into the thing.

So, this is the conundrum.  You'd think that a community of experts could answer a question like this.  And sure, there are probably some experts out here on deep learning that could take a stab at this.  But in reality, the average visitor isn't equipped to be able to do tackle any of these questions.

Is there a way to make these minimal?  Probably not; depends on the nature of the problem.  Machine learning is still such a specialized development space that your average person probably hasn't tried to figure out what "small" means for a typical problem.

> I've been seeing a lot of comments along the lines of *"This isn't what Stack Overflow is for."* This prompts me to question, if not Stack Overflow, where should we as developers turn to?

Dunno.  A group of users who are explicitly dedicated to these types of questions *and* have the means to run them for themselves to approach a solution would be very hard to find on the internet *in general*.

But if someone is able to make the question as narrow/minimal as possible when asking about this, I don't see why it couldn't fit here.  Just don't expect an answer so soon.

Comment: "These are some **really** lofty expectations of the community." Well... I believe in this community. ;)

Comment: @BrockBrown:  Your faith is misplaced.  Look at the typical kinds of questions that get answers.  They all have these hallmarks.  We're not going to invest large amounts of infrastructure, capital or time to answer questions about a relatively niche subject matter unless we were already doing it, and there are *very* select scenarios in which it'd make sense for someone who doesn't do any of this stuff to suddenly start doing it.

Comment: I think it might surprise you how many people would want to volunteer for that sort of effort. A lot of people want to learn about AI, for a billion reasons (art, science, also people don't want to spend their whole lives working), and the best way to learn is to get your hands dirty with stuff that's slightly out of your comfort zone.

Comment: @BrockBrown: Sure, but your conjecture is demonstrating the opposite.  People are asking questions about it on Stack Overflow and they're not finding answers.  The rationale provided is simple enough - people *aren't* reaching for these highly specialized systems *just* for the sake of answering a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: To address the "niche subject matter" and "highly specialized" remarks, I think about a year ago I would agree with you. But as things like ChatGPT emerge, we will get more  systems that are good at solving problems in general. As a result, when someone solves some niche problem someone's model is having (just to pluck one out of the air, "my SOTA generative image model can't make hands"), the answer to the problem will likely also benefit the model in unexpected ways (better overall details). So when you succeed, you make your models more effective at solving your own problems.

Comment: @BrockBrown: So what I just heard was that people should be able to ask ChatGPT about this kind of thing?  What does ChatGPT have to do with Stack Overflow?

Comment: That's not what I said at all. I said that as you get models with increasing capabilities, every time you help solve someone's ML problem you'll see gains in the "general" domain rather than in "specific, niche" domains. This will increase the motivation for this type of volunteer based ML support system. Maybe ChatGPT was a bad example since its innards are a closely guarded secret.

Comment: The best you can usually hope for on stackoverflow are the questions where someone who has the right niche, specialist expertise, can see your question and answer it in 5-10 minutes. This may involve significantly more expertise than average visitor, but its not because they are investing it in your question, its because they happened to have it, and you were lucky they saw your question and applied it. This doesn't happen in the kind of questions where MREs are hard, because they indicate understanding the problem is a significant step.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is my own question, but I thought that I would take a swing at it anyway. There are some answers on here with some pretty useful information that help define the problems at hand more deeply.

Makoto <sup>*(thanks)*</sup> [brings up a really valid point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424807/2121074):

> Is there a way to make these minimal? Probably not; depends on the nature of the problem.

MisterMiyagi <sup>*(thanks)*</sup> [also has a valuable perspective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424821/2121074):

> "We do not require an MRE for debugging because questions without it are unanswerable. We do require an MRE because questions with it are reusable."

If we admit that creating a minimal reproducible example for many of these types of problems might be impossible, but we also acknowledge that the purpose of Stack is to create a library of useful information, and we want to limit aimless [pile stirring](https://xkcd.com/1838/) <sup>(thanks [E_net4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352404/can-we-improve-our-stance-on-off-topic-questions-about-deep-learning))</sup>, what could we do?

Back when computers were just getting started, they could only handle one program at a time. So, folks had to book their turn, run their stuff, take their results and go. Maybe we can tweak this old-school method for a new plan. If one of the major issues is that we can't recreate the asker's setup, *why don't we just run the model right there in the asker's environment*?

I think we'd see lots of repeats of the same chunks of lines added or subtracted in similar locations and contexts. This is due to three main factors:

1. Libraries like `pytorch` and `tensorflow` offer a fairly finite set of components.
2. I suspect that a lot of the solutions will emerge from a relatively modest bag of tricks.
3. People may end up copying the architectures designed here, creating families of architectures with identifiable differences.

As far as thoughts on the 2nd point, I think about what [John Carmack said about AGI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I845O57ZSy4&t=14672s) sometimes:

> I am not a madman for saying that it is likely that the code for artificial general intelligence is going to be tens of thousands of line of code, not millions of lines of code. This is code that conceivably one individual could write, unlike writing a new web browser or operating system and, based on the progress that AI has machine learning had made in the recent decade, **it's likely that the important things that we don't know are relatively simple**. There's probably a handful of things and my bet is I think there's less than six key insights that need to be made. **Each one of them can probably be written on the back of an envelope**.

Small changes can lead to big improvements.
What might happen from this type of thinking is something like chains of incremental improvement that create paths to more effective models. As far as building up a library of useful knowledge, I think we should focus on the **differences** between the starting program and the completed program, and also take into consideration the surrounding text. Here's a small example...

1. Defining the problem: The asker defines their problem, designates a command that will start the program (i.e.: `python main.py`). Types of problems, in broad sweeps, could include categories like *smarter, faster, smaller, error*. The asker could define a function that triggers the *goal state signal* (i.e.: get the verification loss below 0.01) that concludes the program and ends the queue of modifications.
2. The asker gets suggestions for changes based on their code and the type of input/output data. This is not entirely unlike the system we have in place now, to where while someone is writing their question suggestions of possible duplicate questions pop up.
3. Spin up the queue worker. This allows the code to be modified and run on the asker's machine after the asker approves the changes made. The asker can choose which files or directories they would like to be visible to the answerers.
4. Code review and modification: An answerer reviews the problem and proposed solution, making changes to a copy of the code in the asker's environment. A git-style change tracking could visualize what changes were made.
5. Solution approval: The proposed change goes up for review by the asker.
6. Solution execution: Once approved, the altered code is queued and run in the asker's environment. A timeout can be implemented to prevent infinite runs, and the timeout can be made larger or smaller depending on how long the computation is expected to take.
7. Output evaluation: The output of the run is recorded. Comments can be made on whether or not it successfully addresses the issue, or it may trigger the optional goal signal defined in step 1.
8. Solution verification: If the output meets the necessary conditions, the problem is considered solved. If the program is small enough, then the whole program gets recorded as an answer. If the program is large, we can focus on the differences between the initial state and the solved state. If the output doesn't meet the necessary conditions, then run the next item in the queue.

<sup>Please note that while this answer is a little bit scattered and unfocused, I think that something along these lines could be a reasonably close approximation to the approach we're looking for. I feel a little sheepish proposing this because Stack Overflow is already a powerhouse. Maybe this is something that work well better on a different Stack Exchange site? Maybe the queue worker should be managed by another website, and Stack could be like a portal into these types of interactive Q&As, posting urls to interact with it? Again, lightweight solutions if possible seem like they would work the best. Feedback would be greatly appreciated.</sup>