# Should we burninate the [cryptocurrency] and [nft] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

- [cryptocurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptocurrency) - 778 questions
- [nft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nft) - 248 questions

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

While they are in the same wheelhouse as [blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blockchain), blockchains are a generic programming tool, while cryptocurrency and NFT both describe a specific use. We only allow cryptocurrency questions related to APIs. More than a few of these are asking about the concepts from a high level (i.e. How to implement a crypto, etc).

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Some of them are simply off-topic and could be asked on the specific crypto sites (i.e. [Bitcoin.SE](//bitcoin.stackexchange.com)). It's unclear if some of them [are in-scope or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464441/nft-marketplaces-and-storage). Few are obviously on-topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Many are simply "me too" tags for any cryptocurrency questions (even if the question is on-topic). A question about Bitcoin API does not need [nft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nft).

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

For the most part, they describe the same thing. If they were useful tags, they could be synonyms.

Comment: Basically they are as almost all small tags. As they aren:t completly oftopic TT hey should stay alive

Comment: In places the tag is being misused out of a lack of understanding of the platform, but that doesn't mean as a whole it is problematic. There are some good questions in that space, and having them tagged appropriately makes them easier to find and thus more relevant to the community.

Comment: `Many are simply "me too" tags for any cryptocurrency questions (even if the question is on-topic).` You could make that same criticism of, say, the [tag:finance] tag. The general subject of the best way to manage financial assets is not on-topic for StackExchange, and if someone has a question about a specific technology or API, they can tag it with that. Collection of questions on a common subject is valuable, even if the common subject is not, in general, on-topic.

Comment: I don't like the proposal. While they're still small tags, they definitely describe programming topics and should be used there. Like most tags, they also still attract garbage questions, but getting rid of those is the goal of reviewers and moderators. The tag itself has some use.

Comment: @NickODell The existence of another tag should never be used as the justification for keeping a tag around. If there are problems with the [tag:finance] tag then a discussion should be held about that separately. [tag:cryptocurrency] and [tag:nft] cannot adequately describe an on-topic question on their own. Any question that would be on-topic would be able to have a tag that describes a language, tool, framework, or algorithm in addition to [tag:cryptocurrency] or [tag:nft].

Comment: I think @NickODell is making a sound case - the presence of those tags indicates specific subject matter to the coding question, which may make it easier to answer for those familiar with the subject.

Comment: Cryptocurrency and NFT is a lot different.

Comment: @TimotejLeginus They're similar in that they're both things on blockchains that attract WAY more than their fair share of bubbles and snake oil salesmen.

Comment: To quote Shog9:  [DO NOT try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/369403). I agree with Timotej, they're very different. I can see the cryptocurrency tag holding no value since it's broad and overlaps with general blockchain questions, while NFTs are a distinct subtopic with their own programming problems. That they attract loads and loads of crap is unfortunate, but that has never been a reason to burninate.

Comment: Don't forget, people with domain knowledge subscribe to these tags so that questions are targeted towards them.  There's nothing wrong with these tags.  They help get questions answered.  If you have a problem with specific questions, address those questions... not the tags.

Comment: Tbh I don't see the problem. Tags just exist. If people choose to use them randomly or wrongly that's their problem... and in that case their question will probably be of dubious quality anyway. If you fear trash questions with the nft or cryptocurrecy tag, and you ban that, you will just get trash questions with only the blockchain tag. It doesn't solve any problem, except maybe restricting some proper use in the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We are witnessing a similar phenomenon to some tags which cross fields of expertise outside programming. Contrast [blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blockchain) with [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), or even with [chemistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry).

- They both have theoretical grounds which move past the subject of programming, and so such questions are not always on-topic here. When applied to programming, they are generic concepts which are completely agnostic to the technology involved.
- Whether they add something meaningful is also strongly debatable. [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) often conveys much more relevant information than [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) or [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning). They tend to serve as a superset for those who follow the field.
- And, at least speaking for [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), they tend to attract questions which are more about methodology and theoretical concepts in that domain, rather than a specific programming problem, thus becoming a curation time sink.

The plot twist: *we have decided to [keep the chemistry tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342959/should-we-burninate-chemistry)*, and we did our best to *clarify on what grounds are machine learning questions OK to ask here* instead of getting rid of such tags ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380942/standard-for-machine-learning-questions) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378431/guidance-for-asking-machine-learning-questions)). Out past decisions regarding burnination seem to suggest that tags directly referencing something that is not about programming are not necessarily flammable. Approving and initiating burnination for these new tags would be inconsistent with past decisions to keep these other tags for just about the same reasons. We also don't burninate tags for the sole reason that they attract many off-topic questions (otherwise we wouldn't have [kali-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux)).

What this calls is for *stronger, heavier handed curation* over those tags. As much as I find blockchains, cryptocurrencies, and <s>no f'ing thanks</s> non fungible tokens overhyped, this doesn't call for tag burnination, but for adequate cleansing.

Comment: "we did our best to clarify on what grounds are machine learning questions OK to ask here instead of getting rid of such tags" yet we still get loads of off topic questions and the rest is under-performing (half of them never answered). So, I ask, what's to gain for the site to have a generic tag instead of preferring specific tags for software since they are functionally the same? (Basically all questions that don't have a clear programming tag, are off topic)

Comment: @Braiam It is a known issue that sometimes askers are deceived into thinking that such questions are OK due to the presence of such tags. My point is that this is the modus operandi what we have today: we don't just ban generic tags like that. If you want to start a tag revolution in this regard, you'll have to do more than request to burninate these two tags.

Comment: We don't do it, but we haven't shown any benefit of not doing it, or a clear harm from doing it. AFAIK, we've never tried. Maybe we should today, with these tags and see what happens.

Answer (score -20):

If possible, soon these tags will have their own StackExchange site. Check out the Area51 proposal; [Cryptocurrency and Blockchain](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126416/cryptocurrency-and-blockchain?referrer=OTcyYWFhMmUyMzY4NjU4MzEyYmY0MTMwZjFkMjg4NDFiNzg0NGI4ZGE1ZDk5ZmJlYmM3NGQ4NDg3NWRmN2EzNS2PpuJAIfWaWBCa07YtaWDOZ8AFuP59xf4j12foXOKr0). Whenever those questions are not on-topic here, they will surely be perfect there. I propose we wait until the site is ready to launch, then burninate the tags (if you decide it so).

Comment: First of all, that site might never launch, or it might in 10 years, we should not wait for that to happen and accept off-topic stuff here in the meantime. Secondly, even if the site launched, "they will surely be perfect there" is a terribly optimistic view - each site has their own definition of on-topic and there's a lot of crap already with the tags mentioned here that is unlikely to be on-topic anywhere

Comment: Note that some questions can be on-topic on multiple SE sites, so the existence of another site where it is on-topic is not relevant to make it off-topic for SO. The decision should be taken independently.