# Why was my question closed for not being about programming or software development?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020660/how-to-evaluate-a-ml-model-with-no-clear-right-or-wrong-answer) (picture below) about ML and it was closed because it is "*not about programming or software development*."

Even though it really is not a specific code on the page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it states that the question can be on a software algorithm, which it is.
Maybe the question was too broad? I don't know but it is on a specific type of ML algorithm, with no good answer on the internet.

What can I do to reopen this question?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: [Standard for machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380942/2821954), [Guidance for asking machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378431/2821954)

Comment: Why was your question closed? Because we don’t allow, “how would you approach this problem?”, questions on Stack Overflow. You also provide zero specifics. You didn’t ask about an algorithm, you asked for an algorithm, which is out of scope.

Comment: You will want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: It isn't a (real) question. It is the start of a conversation. That is what forums are for ideal for (one of the few things). ([Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).)

Answer (score 16):

"How would you approach this problem" is way too broad for a question. Unfortunately questions like these are closed on Stack Overflow, with the option: *question needs more focus*. In this case, your question was closed as you provided no additional info on what you actually want.

You would usually show what you attempted, found online or explicitly what you want to achieve instead of being vague.

Also, you provided no additional details as to what algorithm you want. Not only that, SO is not a website that writes code for you. Your question should likely ask for "why isn't this working?" for explicit code that you have made or found online to implement. This way users can better understand, fix and explain your code to you.

> I want to build a ML-based algorithm that will help train goalkeepers, by shooting the balls in the best way for them to train.

This is already very complicated. The number of variables you have to keep track and program out is probably insanely large. The algorithm **has** to be partially coded by you so we can understand, else there is nothing we can help you with unfortunately.

> I don't know but it is on a specific type of ML algorithm, with no good answer on the internet.

Please mention it in your question! :3