# Why close after years, based on OP.. request reopen Karan's NN bias topic

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Once upon a time, in the old days, we used to build programs to run [neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) (NNs). When people did not use [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), Google and Nvidia advanced tools, they needed knowledge about the details.

But when you want to apply NNs and deep learning technology on platforms like PLC's that do not provide for TensorFlow versions, you are on your own. Actually writing NN components is quite easy; NN's are still built from scratch. The problem for most people is where to start. There are study questions on Stack Overflow (search for XOR) that are interesting and can be answered.

One of the, IMHO, relevant topics on NN is this one...

*[What is the role of the bias in neural networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/what-is-the-role-of-the-bias-in-neural-networks)*

The opening post was written by Karan in 2010, the last comments are from 2018 and the close was in December 2020. When you click it, you will notice +855 votes for the opening and an answer that got +1472 votes.

On top, there is a **Closed** notification. This opening post is not really clear, so the objection against it is sound and understandable. And closing is a consequence of the rules (?)

But.. why should this legendary topic yielding thousands of votes from members be *closed*? The content in the answers is much more relevant.

*Note* beforehand: I expect questions about the Stack Overflow policy of closing topics with (only) opening post-criteria may have been asked before... but please don't shoot this down on the first day... This is actually a complaint about a *specific* topic, not a general remark about the policy. I just wonder why a high quality topic like this can get parked (that is closed).

Comment: Ok, I will edit my opening post.

Comment: What's "opening post"? A post that you want reopened?

Comment: @yivi The question, you know, the "post" that "opens" discussion (on a forum, in SO's case, opens up to answers)

Comment: @Nick are you sure it means that?

Comment: @yivi *"opening post was written by Karan"* - Yes, the question was written by Karan, *"for the opening and an answer"* - Yes a question goes hand in hand with answers,  *"This opening post is not really clear, so the objection against it is sound and understandable. And closing is a consequence of the rules"* - Yes the question was closed for not following the rules. Also noting it was originally [OP, which means original post in addition to original poster](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424366), I did consider it obvious what opening post meant.

Comment: Good for you, @Nick. I don't consider it obvious at all. That's why I am asking the original poster.

Comment: [Relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/11682469): "OP stands for "Original Poster", the original author of the question or answer under discussion"

Comment: @Jeanne Dark I have read the topic, but I don't think it is applicable in this case. As mensioned above, the topic is 2010 and is about implementation details. It was not closed because of the subject. According to the explanation box, a close choice was made because of question quality, not because of the subject. I do agree with the remarks that most NN topics are actually about statistics. I feel NN and deep learning deserve a separate forum..

Comment: @Nick I now realize the common term here is "Question".

Comment: Relevant: [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250060/11682469)

Comment: Indeed, there's a relevant question. Why would there be a NEED to "flag" this topic.. with the consequences that it appearently has here. Actual closure, possible future removal.. In my humble opiiion this topic is not irrelevant or offtopic or spam. It is interesting content.

Comment: Still, not all interesting content has a place here.

Answer (score 8):

You only need to answer this question:

> Is the given question on-topic today?

If the answer is yes: The question is closed incorrectly

If the answer is no: The question is closed correctly

If you still feel closure is incorrect then we need to have a [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)  discussion.

As far as I'm concerned that question doesn't seem to relate to a practical programming problem. It is more a theory / deeper understanding of the mechanics behind it. Its closure seems appropriate to me.

Arguments like:

- The opening post was written by Karan in 2010
- The last comments are from 2018
- +855 votes for the opening
- an answer that got +1472 votes.
- The content in the answers is much more relevant.

are irrelevant for determining if a question is on-topic or not today.

For reference [we close such questions all the time](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1363500).

If anything, argue for applying an historic lock if the close notice disturbs you so much.

Comment: Hi Rene, I realize that points, year or author are not Meta-arguments (there is no rule to save it ?), but I found this great topic about my favorite subject with thousands of votes being closed for further remarks.. just want to know how you mod-cracks think about the closure decision of december 2020. As a member, I really appreciate this content. Found it via Google.

Comment: @Goodies why does closing bother you so much? The content isn't deleted, we just don't accept new answers to that question.

Comment: Well, maybe I would like to add an answer myself on the subject of NN bias ? and a tweet-size comment box is not always sufficient for a relevant addition. My question here is simply why take down something like this ?  I do ask this as a programmer, see below. But I realize it is blowing in the wind, guess this topic will be closed soon because no one is interested in the subject (?)

Comment: @Goodies it is not taken down. For you or anyone wanting to add an answer there, just create a new question where you describe your practical programming problem with NN bais and you can then self-answer. In either the question or the answer you can link to the beloved post.

Answer (score -7):

I can understand the remarks and comments. Yes, the Stack Overflow is about programming code. Yes, NN is actually 80% statistics and training strategy, which does not really involve coding. Yes, there are tools for NN nowadays.. and questions about the underlying code have become uncommon.

For **today** it may not be on-topic, because there remain little coding issues, except for school work. But... why close a valuable legacy topic about the subject when it still was on-topic? In 2010 I did program my NN ([TDNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_delay_neural_network)) manually! If I had had this topic, I would have been able to introduce some shortcuts in the code, *before* training the NN.

In my daily practice, neural networks and [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) are viewed by management as programming tasks, executed by programmers. They may be scientifically wrong about that, but the thing is.. managers issue assignments. Interesting assignments. So programmers (like me) look for information about NN. I am glad it can be found somewhere.

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Relevant: [SE All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)

Comment: Yeah @Jeanne Dark... maybe i should consider finding other places online, sharing  knowledge. Look into my account. It's all answers and comments. I do my best to *help* collegues. But any objection to the rigid and carved-in-stone rules here seems to end up hitting a brick wall on Meta, every time. Also when the remark seems reasonable. Very frustrating I must say !

Comment: @rene does "on topic today" also count for 10 year old topics ? What's the plan ? clean out SO to keep only things that are "on-topic" for 2021 ? There are questions about iusing the Borland BCC-compiler in MS-DOS without any remarks about "on topic today" like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147337/borland-cant-compile-what-is-going-on-i-cant-even-get-started/1148800#1148800

Comment: Difference is: Borland Compilers are tools used by programmers and questions about it are related to practical programming problems and are therefor still on-topic and probably will be for a long time.

Comment: I voted that up, rene... Interesting point, I used it myself until 2015. People may still work with it, although that is unadvisable. But the same counts for manual programming of NN. Maybe the notion of  what exactly a "programmer" is, should be revised ? In some cases I have needed my programming skills to compose NN training.

Comment: You're free to start that Meta question. That is what I meant about having a "scope" discussion. But I guess it is answered already in: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/do-pure-machine-learning-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You don't need to define what a programmer is: you need to define the tools and practical implementation topics they face. Once a compiler is out of fashion you can find shelter at [Retro Computing.se](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @rene I prefer your previous link. I may be a relatively old programmer, but it's no time to retire when these very interesting new technologies emerge ! Deep-learning systems are the future. Go is solved. I read a news topic about South Korean singer who died 6 years ago, they got his voice back just feeding songs into a NN system. Amazing. Back in time (90's), I worked on a 30.000 lines program for speech recognition. That is all gone. Compliant interfaces are all we need to program, the rest will be ready to run. Better adjust to that situation in time, or we will all end up Retro..

Comment: @rene I read the topic and I agree with AaronLS. Ease up, look at the topic, no single rule of thumb. I now understand your remark, in fact  it is the same discussion we have here.. Karan's topic is an example, maybe I will add an answer there mensioning Karan's topic.